# Amazon S3 files access in Sagemaker instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker

How exactly is file in my S3 bucket is accessible in my Sagemaker instance?
Given that I am not adding any access provision...what exactly is happening in the backend?

Answer (score 2):

For this you want to check your IAM role that you are giving SageMaker. When creating a SageMaker Notebook Instance you also create a role associated with the instance. This instance gives the notebook permission to access other AWS services such as S3, ECR, etc. Depending on the permissions that you have given SageMaker has the functionality to work with those services. In your case S3 is integrated with SageMaker, SageMaker primarily uploads training data, model artifacts and more to S3 thus its essential to have the appropriate role with permissions for S3 read and write access. For a specific example of this check the following link where you give S3 permissions.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/gs-setup-working-env.html

I work for AWS & my opinions are my own